# How to find only the first n elements of DOM

Tags: python, selenium

So I am writing a python 3.7 script using selenium that reacts to messages with an emoji. I find a message, hover over it and click react (with python), than i find all the emojis in the container and click on a certain emoji I want. The problem is, there are 1380 emojis and it takes over 10 seconds to find all the emojis. Is there a way for me to find only the first 200 emojis using .find_elements_by_tag_name('button')

Here is the code:

```
def react(n):
    x = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('DMBLb')[-1]  # This gets the las message
    hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(x)  # Hovers over the message
    hover.perform()
    x.find_elements_by_class_name('wpO6b')[2].click()  # Clicks the react button
    emoji_container = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('_01UL2')[0]
    sleep(1)
    emoji_container.find_elements_by_tag_name('button')[n].click()  # Since all the emojis are buttons, and there is nothing except for emojis in the container I just search for all the buttons
```

Since I will only ever use the first 200 emojis it is a complete waste of time for python to find all the emojis, so is there a way for me to find only the first 200 buttons in the container?

Comment: Instead of getting all buttons and select item `n`. Use an identifier that goes right to the one you want:  `emoji_container.find_element_by_xpath('//button['+str(n)+']').click()` or   `emoji_container.find_element_by_css('button['+str(n)+']').click()`

Comment: Instead of sleeping for a fixed amount of time, which is wasteful (you end up sleeping longer than you need to), after you create your driver issue a `driver.implicitly_wait(n)` where `n` is the maximum number of seconds you are willing to wait for a `find_elements` to succeed. You can specify a number much greater than 1 if you want. If following the call to `click()` the element you are next looking for appears within a quarter of a second, you will only wait for a quarter of a second (but up to `n` seconds before you timeout).